# Download some data in first run of a app

Tags: android

I am making an app which uses a lot of resources. So, It might not be better to store all of them in assets folder. I want something such that my app can download the data needed and store them somewhere where it can access. I need to download data once in every update.
This will make the app size smaller as well as the maintenance of future updates will be easy. How can I do that?

Comment: How do you download something or do it only once? What attempts have you made already?

Comment: You can't store them in assets after packaging, use phone's internal memory for data saving by the use of SharedPreference or DB

Comment: I need to download some data once, in every update. But only once.  
I didn't make any attempts.

Comment: Oh. I dont need to store them in assets. actually I need them in internal memory. My app is copying files from the assets to memory in first run with some initializations. 
But I tested the app with a few data. But when there will be huge data it is not a good choice to store then in assets

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Backendless](https://backendless.com) [FileAPI](https://backendless.com/documentation/files/android/files_overview.htm)  or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) from Google for storing all data that you need, and then just show progress dialog and download them at first start. And then just check if you already have this files.